# Building openVibe sources

Tags: dependencies, cmake, lua

I want to build the [openVibe](http://openvibe.inria.fr/downloads/) , but the following error appear after running the sell script `./linux_build`  :

> FAILED to find GTK+... CMake Error at
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108
>   (message):   Could NOT find Lua51 (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES
>   LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindLua51.cmake:76
>   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
>   cmake-modules/FindThirdPartyLua.cmake:9 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>   plugins/processing/stimulation/CMakeLists.txt:22 (INCLUDE)

Comment: @dobey , my question is about a problem that i face it when compiling or installing a app , and it has not a relation with what you give !

Comment: Your problem is a general question of "how to build something from source." You need to install the required dependencies to build anything from source. The errors clearly state what dependencies are missing. Having a question for answering what dependencies are needed to build every random library or application available, is unreasonable and not something the site can do.

Comment: @dobey , all dependencies are installed(including GTK and lua) , but the problem still happened

Comment: You didn't install the development packages then, only the runtimes.

Comment: You need to install the appropriate `-dev` packages as well. For example, `libgtk2.0-dev` if it requires the 2.x GTK+ API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the linux-install_dependencies.sh script in the scripts folder of the repository to install all the required dependencies automatically